# local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio donde he definido dos funciones, una función `random` que devuelve un valor del *0 al 2* y esos numero están asignados a piedra, papel o tijera. Y una función que pregunta al usuario si quiere mostrar piedra, papel o tijera.

Ahora mismo estoy comparando el resultado del usuario y el resultado `Random` para ver quién gana el juego piedra, papel o tijera. Sin embargo una vez que escribo el código recibo el

> warning: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment.

Adjunto el código, ¿cuál puede ser el error?

```py
def ganador(player, computadora):  
    if (player == 'rock' and computadora == 'rock'):
        result = 0
    elif (player == 'rock' and computadora == 'scissors'):
        result = 2
    elif (player == 'rock' and computadora == 'paper'):
        result = 1
    elif (player == 'scissors' and computadora == 'scissors'):
        result = 0
    elif (player== 'scissors' and computadora == 'paper'):
        result = 2
    elif (player == 'scissors' and computadora == 'rock'):
        result = 1
    elif player == 'paper' and computadora == 'paper':
        result = 0
    elif player == 'paper' and computadora == 'scissors':
        result = 2
    elif player == 'paper' and computadora == 'rock':
        result = 1     
    return(result)

player = question(player)
computadora = gesture(gesto)
win = ganador(player, computadora)
```

Comment: Eso pasa porque **ningún condicional se cumple** por lo que en `return result` la variable  `result` no ha sido definida, intentando referenciar el objeto asociado a ella antes de que exista y se le asignara alguno. Debes estar pasando mal los argumentos a la función para que ninguno de los condicionales se cumpla. Por ejemplo, `ganador("rock", "Paper")` genera dicho error. `question` o `gesture` están haciendo algo mal..., puedes colocar un `print(player, computadora)` dentro de `ganador` antes del `return` a ver que está recibiendo cuando el error se lanza.

Comment: También puede darse el caso de que no tengas una excepción, funcionando el código correctamente, sino solo un warning del linter de turno del IDE que uses, en este caso puedes evitarlo de muchas forma, simplemente agregando `result = None` antes del primer `if` o agregar `else: result = None` al final del último `elif`. La idea es que `result` siempre exista el momento del `return`. Lo digo porque mencionas "recibo el warning:", en el primer caso (primer comentario) lo que recibes no es un warnig sino una excepción (terminando la ejecución) de tipo `UnboundLocalError`.